# how to configure slack to display jenkins build status?

Tags: jenkins, slack, hubot

how do I configure slack and jenkins -
to get jenkins build statuses (with link to build) into specific slack room,
automatically after build is finish ?

Answer (score 3):

found an answer to my question in slack site,
after installing jenkins plugin in slack 
(from : https://hubot-nga.slack.com/apps)
I got detailed instructions + unique team-domain and integration token.
in addition all the required steps to complete the integration in jenkins.

Comment: In my case, ${BUILD_STATUS} is appearing as as in Slack channel. Below is the reference in my slack channel.

       `Jenkins Build Notification - http://185.15.15.15:8080/-400-${BUILD_STATUS}`

Why  `BUILD_STATUS` is not showing with failed/passed.